# Hide "Run code snippet" on non-HTML/CSS/Javascript questions

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50b2a44d-69b3-4470-977e-7e8061f18750)<sup>1</sup> seems interesting because it has individual snippets for each file, essentially functioning as an accordian. I can easily look at one file at a time without having to scroll through walls of text whenever I want to look at something. This is similar to the region/code folding function of text editors.

Technically it's already implemented, all that really needs to be done is to hide the "run code snippet" button if the language tagged isn't HTML/JS/CSS.

Would this be good UX or appealing to other users?

<sup>1</sup> I linked to a specific revision because somebody is currently failing at editing the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081643/why-is-my-int-arr-length-returning-1) and making it look *worse*.

Comment: @Gothdo They don't appear in the "specific revision" view. And it was edited out in the latest revision. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37081643/revisions). But again as I said, it's kind of messy because it took the editor 5 tries to remove the snippets.

Comment: @Gothdo What? Re-read my question...

Comment: OK you seem to be missing the point entirely. Yes I know Stack Snippets are inappropriate for anything but those languages. My point is by *accident* they seem to function perfectly well as a code folding feature, and without a run snippet button, that's essentially what it is. I'm asking if anybody else thinks this is a good idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they denied this feature request on MSE already. But technically, nobody is stopping you from using SS to render the code in your snippet, I guess. (But you probably deserve down votes if you actually try that.)

Comment: @user6292850: Please don't link to revisions. Link to the actual question, instead.

Answer (score 7):

I don't approve this idea. Stack Snippets are designed to contain *runnable* HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. I don't see a point in using them for other languages. Using just a code block is enough.

Also, a question which contains such a large amount of code definitely doesn't have a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example.